# Why did Ned and Robert grow up under the care of Jon Arryn?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

It's mentioned that Jon Arryn was like a father to Ned and Robert, as he brought them up.

By why did they grow up with him?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the Westerosi version of the medieval European practice of [fostering](http://www.ultimatehistoryproject.com/medieval-childhood-the-life-of-william-marshal.html):

> Later in their childhood, between the ages of 8 and 10, boys – and 
>   occasionally girls, too – of knightly and noble status would be sent away to live 
>   with another noble family for a few years in a custom called **fostering.** Sometimes 
>   the foster family would be related to the birth parents; William Marshal fostered 
>   with his cousin William of Tancarville. More often than not, though, foster 
>   parents were chosen for political rather than familial connections. The royal 
>   household was an especially prestigious place to foster; some royal households 
>   had upwards of 100 young men and women in their care.
>
> Fostering helped young nobles make connections with other families while 
>   training them in the skills they would need as adult members of the aristocracy. 
>   Spending time with young people of a similar age and social class would – or so 
>   their parents hoped – strengthen the political bonds among the next generation of 
>   the nobility, and maybe even enable them to find a potential spouse.

As Lord of the Vale, Jon Arryn was one of the most powerful noblemen in the Seven Kingdoms. On a personal level, he was well known for his wisdom and sense of honour. Therefore, he was a logical choice to foster the sons of similarly powerful families, such as the Starks and Baratheons.

Comment: I believe they're referred to as "Wards" in the book

Comment: @Liath Wards are different. Wards are political hostages, not voluntary guests. For example Theon Greyjoy was kept as a ward at Winterfell to keep Balon Greyjoy in line after he bent the knee to Robert Baratheon.

Comment: @RobSobers -- I'm not sure about that, I think "ward" covers both. It could be a fosterling from an ally, or it could be a polite term for a hostage taken from an enemy.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Ah, you are correct. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

They were sent by their parents to be "fostered" by Lord Arryn. This is a common practice among the noble families of Westeros, as it creates better ties among close allies (including better potential for marriages) and ensures the loyalty of not-so-close allies (the children are basically hostages in that case, an example is Theon Greyjoy).

Comment: I agree that was what Catelyn was going to do in the first book to get someone to help fund her war with the Lannisters. Maybe you should qoute that.